# Change pandas date by workdays

Tags: python, date, weekday

I would like to increase the date in my pandas column by 1 workday, that is, if the date is a Monday, Jan 21st, I want to change it to Tuesday, Jan 22nd, but if the date is Friday Jan 25th, then I want to increase it to Monday Jan 28th.

This is what I would do to do the simple version of just increasing it by 1 day:

new_date = old_date + datetime.timedelta(days=+1)

Is there a function that accounts for workdays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use this,

```python
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay
new_date = old_date + BDay(1)
```

more info [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects)

Comment: Very nice!!! Thank you so much, thanks for the link too, that will come in handy!!